# How to add map.scale

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I'm trying to add a map scale to my map but no progress so far.
I've a shapefile from which I selected some polygons as follows:

```
library(rgeos)
region <- readOGR("region.shp")
subset <- region[region$cod=='6000']
writeOGR(subset, ".", "subset", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
subset <- readOGR("subset.shp")
```

Subsequently, I selected the point in which I would like to locate the map.scale:

```
locator(1)
$x
[1] 462296.1
$y
[1] 4941701
```

Finally the map.scale:

```
plot(subset)
library(maps)
maps::map.scale(461574.1, 4942760, relwidth = 0.15, ratio = FALSE)
```

This returns me this message

Warning message:
In maps::map.scale(461574.1, 4942760, relwidth = 0.15, ratio = FALSE) :
  location of scale out of this world!

and this plot

[image: subsetPLOT]

while I would like to obtain something like this:

[image: examplePLOT]

Could you please tell me what went wrong?

Comment: It looks like your shapefile layer's CRS projection is off. `map.scale()` gives that warning message when absolute value of the 2nd argument (i.e. longitude) exceeds 90. But it looks like it still produced the scale anyway, just that it got cut off at the edge. You may want to shift the location inwards. And if you want that arrow, try `GISTools::north.arrow`.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I tried to modify coordinates but result did not change